# Get MINUS data beween two files in UNIX

Tags: unix, cat

I have two files in Unix.

File 1 contain:

```
1.- Jhon
2.- Peter
3.- Marie
```

File 2 contain:

```
2.- Peter
5.- Luouis
```

I want to create a new file from these two file.
The result that I want is:

File 3:

```
1.- Jhon
3.- Marie
```

Basically the result is like next below:

[image]

But unfortunately, the result is like this:

File 3:

```
1.- Jhon
3.- Marie
5.- Luouis
```

I want the MINUS from file 1 to file 3, and not the DISTINCT between both files

The command that I'm using is:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort  | uniq -u  > file3
```

Any suggest for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
comm -23 file1.txt file2.txt
```

From the docs:

> **NAME**
>           comm - compare two sorted files line by line
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>           comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2
>
> .............
>
> -1     suppress lines unique to FILE1
>
> -2     suppress lines unique to FILE2
>
> -3     suppress lines that appear in both files

or you can try like this:

```
fgrep -v -f file1 file2
```

Comment: Hi, but the result of this differences I want to keep in file3. It's possible? I don't want to modify the file1 and file2

Comment: @KhristianLiahut:- Then you can simply add it to 3 files like this: `comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file3`